# UIGestureRecognizer vs. UITouch Delegate Performance

Tags: ios, cocoa, drawing, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I am writing an app for drawing.
My main question is: How do I get the best performance from touch events?

Is there a difference between `UIGestureRecognizer` and `UITouch` Delegates?
Are there different refresh rates or sth.?

Best 
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a drawing app you should use `UITouch` delegates because it will be faster then other `UIGestureRecognizer`. The reason is whenever a tap event occurs in that case the UIEvent of tap action is traversed thorough the `UIResponder` chain and transmitted to the `UIResponder` which is responding to the tapped event. So if you'll add a `UIGesture` on top of a view then there will be an extra machine cycle to check the `UIGesture` in responder chain which is not worthy for a drawing apps cause these apps should be much faster in responding to taps.

All you need is to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the view where you want to draw.